# FoxitReader starting up after saving file in gscan2pdf

Tags: pdf

Some time ago I installed the proprietary [FoxitReader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) to use it for PDF annotation. I don't use it myself - I was testing it for third party use. But I still have it installed.

I use [`gscan2pdf`](http://gscan2pdf.sourceforge.net/) to scan to PDF. That's my default choice for scanning.

After installing `FoxitReader` (I can't remember for how long) I've noticed the following curiosity. Once I save a file scanned by `gscan2pdf` to disk, `FoxitReader` opens up by itself with that file open. I've no idea what could be causing that. I'm certain I haven't written any script to do so, nor can I think of any reason I would do so, since I don't actually use `FoxitReader`.

I'd like to know why this is happening, in part because of simple curiosity, and in part because I would like to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In gscan2pdf:

-->Preferences-->General options: disable the checkbox "View files on saving"